# Spring Boot App - Fails to bootRun

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle, spring-cloud

I am trying to create a simple Spring Boot application using Gradle in Mac.
On gradle bootRun, I get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

  > Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

> Exception raised at:
>   2015-08-23 01:37:57.989  WARN 6186 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: void org.springframework.cache.annotation.AbstractCachingConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.Collection); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.config.annotation.ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.ListableStackResourceFactory org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.config.annotation.ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration.stackResourceFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.config.annotation.ContextStackConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No valid instance id defined
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)

The build.gradle looks like below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
//apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

//sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
    baseName = 'myApp'
    version =  '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

}

repositories {
    //mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/release/" }
}

dependencyManagement {
     imports {
          mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws:1.0.2.RELEASE'
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-jdbc")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow")
    compile("postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc4")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

Any help over here?

Answer (score 3):

Cause of the exception is EC2 environment configuration is not defined in the configuration file. Since you are running this application on a local machine I assume you don't need it.

**Solution**

Remove the following from your gradle file and see if everything is normal.

```
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-jdbc")
```

The above mentioned dependencies are only applicable to spring application designed to run in EC2 environment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had precisely the same issue and the dependency that seemed to be the culprit for me was `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'`

Answer (score 0):

inside `src/main/resources`

open file `application.properties`

and change the port (set port num as you line), add this line:
`server.port=1337`

Same worked for me.

And finally type: `./gradlew bootRun`